# Allow shell script to accept "~/" as file descriptor

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a small part of a shell script that reads an input file from a user and saves it to a variable img_dir:

```
read -e -p "Enter img_folder filename: " img_dir
```

A user will most likely want to enter a folder in the home directory. But this command does not support that tilde thing (what is it called?) "~/xxx", you have to use "/home/usr/xxx". Is there a way to make it support the tilde function?

Comment: Tilde expansion is done by the shell, not by your program. You need to tell the shell to evaluate your variable to do that.